# Ubuntu: disable udev's persistent-net-generator.rules

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, udev

I'm using [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/server/overview) and I am modifying `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to define my own mappings of ethernet interfaces to MAC addresses; that file is initially generated by rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules` at system installation time (or at the first boot, I actually don't know and it doesn't matter here).

How can I be sure that my edited version will never ever be overwritten by anything?

Removing the persistent-net-generator, as suggested on some websites, is not the *Right Thing™* to do as told by comments in the file itself: it will be overwritten by any update of the `udev` package. I'm looking for a more formally correct way to disable it.

Is it enough to just make sure that `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` does exist?
Maybe there are other events that could trigger its regeneration? (eg. adding or removing ethernet interfaces to the system?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to disable the generator is to override it with an empty file. Any rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d` will take precedence over rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d`, so simply create an empty file or symlink to `/dev/null`:

```
sudo touch /etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
-OR-
sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
```

This is safe and future-proof.

Comment: It's probably better to just touch an empty file.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look on this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/README` Then you can read, that your own udev rules file should have higher number in its name, than the `75-persistent-net-generator.rules`. So create a new rules file named like `/etc/udev/rules.d/76-persistent-net.rules` with your own settings.

Comment: No such file exists on Debian 8.2, so it must not be a reliable source. Anyway, won't this cause both files to be invoked? AFAIK in such situations, both files must have exactly the same name in order to invoke precedence/masking, and leading numbers are considered a different that prevents masking.

Answer (score -1):

Additional cents for presenting this rule from being re- generated in a batch. Usually I use this at our DevOps practice

```
for i in `cat /tmp/allnode.lst | awk '{print $1}'`; do echo $i; \
ssh $i 'mv /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules /tmp/'; done
```

Col 1 in allnode.lst is IP address